# Parse string from an array. Error Code: 'json' has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, arrays, json, string, curl

How can I get String Results from an Array?

My Code looks like this:

`#Start 10 highest Results`

`print("High Results:")`
`print("Doing request")`

`headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8", "ApiAccessKey": "ExampleKey", "ApiSecretKey":  "Example Key"}`
`response = requests.get("https://www.example.com/", headers=headers, verify=False)`
`print("writing response code")`
`print(response)`

`print(response.content ) # Return the raw bytes of the data payload`
`print("----------------------------------")`

`json_object = json.loads(response.text)`
`json_formatted_str = json.dumps(json_object, indent=2)`
`print(json_formatted_str)`

`y = json.str(response.content)`

`#Display only High Results`
`print(y[0]["High"])`

`print("done")`

The Error I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "./CurlRequest.py", line 71, in <module>`
`y = json.str(response.content)`
`AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'str'`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the response is a JSON, then you should simply do `y = response.json()`. Afterwards, if you want to filter out all of the entries in `y` where the field `RiskLevel` equals `"High"`, you can do:

```
for key in y:
   if y[key]["RiskLevel"] == "High":
      # do something with the entry
      print(y[key])
```

Comment: Now I get `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Just do `print(y)` and post the results, otherwise it's impossible to help you. Obviously `y` is a dictionary and not an array.

Comment: Can I do print(y[High]) to Filter only the Results with the Name High. Because there are Medium and High results but I only need the High ones

Comment: If `print(y)` looks something like `{"High": [...], "Medium": [...]}`, then you can also do `print(y["High"]`.

Comment: High looks like this: `"RiskLevel": "High",`

Comment: man can you just show what `print(y)` outputs, you are extremely being difficult.

Comment: In the code which I posted I have a curl command for Server Tests. I can't show the curl put it returns me tests with a RiskLevel and there I need to filter high out of it.    

Output Example: 
` { ` <br />
      `"Id": "1b91afd20-67c3-4c5a-8f50-573c98d3dzg9",`<br />
      `"CvssBaseScore": 10.0,`<br />
     `"RiskLevel": "High",`<br />
     ` "Name": "Multiple Vulnerabilities"`<br />
   ` },`<br />

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Can you please just show the output of `print(y)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./CurlRequest.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(y["High"])
KeyError: 'High'

Comment: Can you please just show the output of `print(y)`

Comment: That is the output what else do you want?

Comment: No, that was the output of `print(y["High"])`. Can you please just show me the output of `print(y)`

Comment: It is written in 1 line and too long to copy it in but it looks like the code I wrote above: "Id": "1b91afd20-67c3-4c5a-8f50-573c98d3dzg9", "CvssBaseScore": 10.0, "RiskLevel": "High",

Comment: So what you actually want is all the entries of `y` where `RiskLevel` equals `"High"`?

Comment: But is there only a single entry in `y` or are there multiple ones? Is the output of `print(y)` like `{"id1": {"RiskLevel": "High", "x": "y", ...}, "id2":  {"RiskLevel": "Low", "x": "y", ...}}`?

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer. See if it helps and accept it if so.

Comment: For Example one Output with RiskLevel High and One with Medium: 
`"Id": "02153d99-630e-4539-bd38-b68276fc905d",`
     ` "CvssBaseScore": 7.8,`
     ` "RiskLevel": "High",`
      `"Name": "OpenSSH before 7.3 Denial of Service Vulnerability"`


`"Id": "ca841c93-1d29-4195-a0f5-fzca92469t56",`
      `"CvssBaseScore": 6.9,`
     ` "RiskLevel": "Medium",`
     ` "Name": "OpenSSH before 7.4 Privilege Escalation Vulnerability"`

Comment: I am sorry I cant edit it good It looks horrible.

Comment: I tried it but I get this Error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: As long as you fail to show me what the JSON response looks like I can not help you. Also I am getting increasingly demotivated since you seem to be putting zero effort of your own into it. Update your original question with the JSON response without cutting any necessary parts out of it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am a student and it is my second day working with python and I try to figure out what I'm doing wrong.